# Bypass Windows GUI completely

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

Say I want to create a computer for end-users that uses Windows but the average user should generally not have to think about the fact that it is a Windows PC (except for minimum notifications required by Microsoft, fine print, etc). This computer would have its own custom GUI and file explorer, and the average user would have no need to access the underlying Windows OS.

You might think of it as custom devices made by manufacturers that run Linux under the hood, except I want to use Windows. The reason I want to use Windows is because I would want the end-user to be able to play games made for Windows.

For instance, some features needed would be:

- A replacement startup animation for Windows
- No Windows Explorer / desktop at all - it would just load my GUI. Maybe this GUI simply overlays Explorer - that would be ok as long as it comes first.
- Windows key, Ctrl Alt Delete, other functions would be disabled unless explicitly allowed by a super user.

I am not aware if Microsoft provides a way for device manufacturers to do this kind of thing without getting crazy hacky. Is there some kind of streamlined way to do this with a Windows PC? I have seen at least one device for end-users (a live-cam stream software / hardware package) that ran Windows - although they didn't do a perfect job of hiding that it was Windows, they at least overlayed the GUI and replaced the start animations.

Comment: I very much doubt it. Especially the [SAK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_attention_key) shouldn't be possible to disable without hacking the kernel and/or other similar, low-level components of the OS; it would sort of defeat its purpose if it could be intercepted by non-OS software. That said, you might want to have a look at [Windows Embedded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Embedded), but that will almost certainly fail your requirement of being able to play commonly available games. Which seems to be at odds with your requirement that the end user should not see it as Windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can start any program as shell, and it would completely replace the desktop, start menu and task bar.

It will then only start that program. Any program started from there will be shown on the main screen and its GUI will appear normal as it would do otherwise (windows buttons etc) unless you use an alternative shell.

For example, you could start steam's big picture as shell and it will launch that when you start windows. Certain windows keys are disabled, but not all. A policy could alter this to fit your needs.

The only thing you are unlikely to get done is a windows startup animation. It is possible but not easy.

To alter the shell, open regedit on the user for which you want to apply this, and go to:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System
```

At the right, double click `Shell` and enter the path for the executable that should replace the shell, for example `c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe`

Be warned: if your alternative shell path is invalid or the new program does not offer a way to start an explorer or regedit, and you have no alternative users on this computer you may not be able to undo the changes.

Creating a system restore point prior to changing this is advised, as it would allow you to move back to this point and undo your changes would things go wrong.

Alternatively, install a virtual machine (such as Oracle VirtualBox), install windows in it, and experiment with this in there to see how it works. VirtualBox allows you to revert to a previous snapshot when powering off or at your command.